# Problems with nullity and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Hi could you please help me solve the given problem below?

Let V be finite-dimensional over F and f be a linear operator on V. If k is a positive integer, let $$
f^k=f\omicron f \omicron ....\omicron f \hspace{1cm} (f\hspace{.1cm} written\hspace{.1cm}k\hspace{.1cm}times)
$$

Use the definition of nullity to show that there exists a least positive integer m such that $$
nullity(f^m)=nullity(f^{m+k})\hspace{.1cm}
$$
,for all positive integers k.

I really don't know where to start. I'm new to linear algebra. I know the definition of nullity but still struggling with problems like this. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

---

Thanks. So let's start with what the first comment is suggesting (from AnlamK)

let v∈V, and B={v1,v2,v3,...,vn} a basis for V, B'={v1,v2,v3,..,vm} be a basis for ker f. Then,

$$
v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n\, \, \, then, 
$$
$$
f(v)=a_1f(v_1)+a_2f(v_2)+...+a_nf(v_n)\, 
$$
$$
f^1(v)=a_1f(f(v_1))+a_2f(f(v_2))+...+a_nf(f(v_n))\,
$$
$$
f^2(v)=a_1f^2(v_1)+a_2f^2(v_2)+...+a_nf^2(v_n)\,\,\,\,and\,\,so\,\,on, until f^k
$$
$$
f^k(v)=a_1f^k(v_1)+a_2f^k(v_2)+...+a_nf^k(v_n)
$$

Some elements will go to the zero vector and the other will go to the image of f. The number of elements after we take f^k(v) still have the same number of elements after taking f(v). Which means that

$$
f^{k+1}(v)=a_1f^{k+1}(v_1)+a_2f^{k+1}(v_2)+...+a_nf^{k+1}(v_n)
$$
$$
f^{k+m}(v)=a_1f^{k+m}(v_1)+a_2f^{k+m}(v_2)+...+a_nf^{k+m}(v_n)
$$

So if the nullity of f is m, then the nullity of f^k and f^k+m is still equal to m,

$$
nullity(f^k)=nullity(f^{k+m})
$$

Comment: Let me try to give a hint. Write any vector $v \in V$ in terms of a basis in $V$ and try to see what happens when you apply $f$ successively.

Comment: Thanks, i have edited my question. Is my logic correct? thanks!

Comment: I am not such an expert myself but looks correct to me more or less - don’t count on me. You say some elements will go to the zero vector and others will go to the image of f. This point needs elaborating. $f(v)$ could go to the image of f but $f^2(v)$ could be zero. (Think of differentiation operator and polynomials of degree 1.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show $\text{nullspace}(f^k) \subseteq \text{nullspace}(f^{k+1})$. What does that say about the sequence $\text{nullity}(f), \text{nullity}(f^2), \text{nullity}(f^3), \text{nullity}(f^4), \ldots$?

Hint: the nullspaces of the $f^k$ are all subspaces of $V$ which is finite dimensional. Thus $\text{nullity}(f^k)$ can be no larger than what number?

---

Edit for more detail:

The first hint implies that
$$\text{nullity}(f) \le \text{nullity}(f^2) \le \text{nullity}(f^3) \le \text{nullity}(f^4) \le \cdots.$$
The second hint implies that all the nullities in this sequence are no more than $\dim V$. Therefore at some point this sequence of nullities becomes constant.

Comment: if i take the f^1, f^2, and so on up to f^k. The number of elements will still be the same. So if i take the nullity of every succeeding f, the the nullity of the last f is still the same as the first. Is that correct?